# Cannot convert value of type

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, cloudinary

In my Project, I use Cloudinary, while I using the following function in Xcode 7.3 it's working fine But in Xcode 8 I got error.

> (Cannot convert value of type ([AnyHashable: Any]!,String!,Int!,AnyObject) -> () to expected argument type (CLUploaderCompletion).

How to I solve this error.

```
uploader.upload(forUpload, options: nil, withCompletion:onCloudinaryCompletion, andProgress:onCloudinaryProgress)


func onCloudinaryCompletion(_ successResult:[AnyHashable: Any]!, errorResult:String!, code:Int, idContext:AnyObject!) {
    print("successResult\(successResult)")
}

func onCloudinaryProgress(_ bytesWritten:Int, totalBytesWritten:Int, totalBytesExpectedToWrite:Int, idContext:AnyObject!) {        
    print("onCloudinaryProgress")

}
```

**Screenshot** of the error:

[image]

Comment: Anybody Having idea to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swift 3 some things have changed and one of those is that `id` from objective c is now `Any` in swift instead of `AnyObject`. Change your `idContext` to type `Any`.

Also you must also change the type of your dictionary and the string to an optional. So it becomes `String?` and `[AnyHashable: Any]?`.

Comment: I changed the idContext type from AnyObject to Any, but still, I have the same error.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Majster, Thanks for saving me. Your solution is working for me.

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. The checkmark next to the answer.